# How to checked permissions in edit user form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form (thanks Alasdair):

```
class PermissionsModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s" % obj.name


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=u'First name', required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=u'Last name', required=True)
    permissions = PermissionsModelMultipleChoiceField(Permission.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super( NewUserForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        ctypes = ContentType.objects.filter(
            Q(app_label='articles') |
            Q(app_label='tags')
        )
        self.fields['permissions'].queryset = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__in=ctypes)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

And in template permissions shows me permissions something like this:

```
[] Can change article
[] Can delete article
[] Can view article

[...]
```

calling form:

```
profile_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=profile_user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        [... here will save permissions ...]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
else:
    form = UserForm(instance=profile_user)
```

How to set checked in template this permissions which are assigned to edited user?

Comment: I don't understand quite well, you want to show the checkboxes as **checked** if the user has that particular permission?

Comment: Yes, for example if user has a "Can view article" parmission, I want to check this checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the argument `data` to populate the checkboxes when you instantiate the form (only outside the `POST` request) like this:

```
profile_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=profile_user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        [... here will save permissions ...]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
else:
    user_permissions_list = # place here the query to get the profile_user permissions
    form = UserForm(instance=profile_user, data={'permissions':user_permissions_list})
```

Using `data` is the key to mark the checkboxes according to user actual permissions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: but how to get user_permissions_list? user.get_all_permissions() return me list of permission names

Comment: what permissions engine are you using? django-guardian? or normal django permissions

Comment: Normal django permissions. If I set for exaple: [...]data={'permissions':[23,24,25]} then it works. (23,24,25 - id of permission objects)

Comment: I answer your other question where you ask that specifically.