# How to get user permissions?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I want to retrieve all permission for user as list of premission id's but:

```
user.get_all_permissions()
```

give me list of permission names. How to do it?

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: I need this to set proper checkboxes in ModelMultipleChoiceField in my form

Comment: are you exposing permissions to the application? it is not a good idea.

Comment: In my app I have custom form for adding users and I shows some permissions (for my app) as checkboxes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565277/how-to-checked-permissions-in-edit-user-form

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The key is get the permission objects like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=user)
```

and there you can access the `id` property like this:

```
permissions[0].id
```

If you want the list `(id, permission_name)` do the following:

```
perm_tuple = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Permission.objects.filter(user=user)]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What if the user is in a group which has that permission ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar I've hadden an aswer to address this issue you pointed out.

Comment: Like what @AmoghTalpallikar said, this doesn't cover the case when a group has a permission the user does not but the user is a member of that group.

Comment: For people using Django 3.0+ : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290977/6410464

Answer (score 51):

to get all the permissions of a given user, also the permissions associated with a group this user is part of:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def get_user_permissions(user):
    if user.is_superuser:
        return Permission.objects.all()
    return user.user_permissions.all() | Permission.objects.filter(group__user=user)
```

Comment: I'm using this code but for some reason it's returning duplicate permissions.

Comment: Here's an option for removing duplicates (presumably because they're group and user permissions): `list(set(chain(user.user_permissions.filter(content_type=ctype).values_list('codename', flat=True), Permission.objects.filter(group__user=user, content_type=ctype).values_list('codename', flat=True))))` Suspect chain is sometimes more efficient than |. The values_list calls and filter by content type are unnecessary but are further options depending on your needs.

Comment: I guess `return Permission.objects.filter(Q(group__in=user.groups.all())|Q(user=user)).distinct()` will dedup as well.

Comment: It should be noted that although `user.has_perm("...")` will always return `True` for superusers, the user may not actually be associated with any `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission` records in the database. Also, revoking superuser status does not remove permission relationships from the user record.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Django 3.0+, `user.get_user_permissions()` gives the codename of all the permissions.

More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_user_permissions

Answer (score 8):

we can get user permission from user objects directly into a list like this

```
perm_list = user_obj.user_permissions.all().values_list('codename', flat=True)
```

Try this....

Answer (score 5):

This is an routine to query for the Permission objects returned by `user.get_all_permissions()` in a single query.

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def get_user_permission_objects(user):
    user_permission_strings = user.get_all_permissions()
    if len(user_permission_strings) > 0:
        perm_comps = [perm_string.split('.', 1) for perm_string in user_permission_strings]
        q_query = reduce(
            or_,
            [Q(content_type__app_label=app_label) & Q(codename=codename) for app_label, codename in perm_comps]
        )
        return Permission.objects.filter(q_query)
    else:
        return Permission.objects.none()
```

Alternatively, querying Permission directly:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def get_user_permission_objects(user):
    if user.is_superuser:
        return Permission.objects.all()
    else:
        return Permission.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(group__user=user)).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=user)

permissions[0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns the set of permission strings the user_obj has, including both user permissions and group permissions. Returns an empty set if is_anonymous or is_active is False.

`user_permissions_list = request.user.get_all_permissions()`

Returns the set of permission strings the user_obj has from the permissions of the groups they belong. Returns an empty set if is_anonymous or is_active is False.

`request.user.get_group_permissions()`

Returns the set of permission strings the user_obj has from their own user permissions. Returns an empty set if is_anonymous or is_active is False.

`request.user.get_user_permissions()`

Unfortunately these built in method give me duplicate queries.

Or you can use your own filter from permission tables to get all permissions of current user

`user_permissions_list = list(Permission.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user) | Q(group__user=request.user)).values_list('codename', flat=True))`

[Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.get_all_permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Extending and explaining the answer from @Shihabudheen K M

we can get user permission from user objects directly a queryset like this

```
perm_queryset = user_obj.user_permissions.all().values_list('id')
```

The queryset obtained in this case is of the following format:

```
<QuerySet [(31,), (16,), (11,), (35,), (18,), (36,)]>
```

Flattened queryset of permissions of the user:

```
flattened_perm_queryset = user_obj.user_permissions.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [31, 16, 11, 35, 18, 36]>
```

To get a list of the ids of these permissions on a user you can do:

```
perm_list = list(user_obj.user_permissions.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Output:

```
[31, 16, 11, 35, 18, 36]
```

Hope this is helpful!