# How to check has_perm of user groups?

Tags: django, permissions

I have created a group and also assigned some permissions. Added some users in this group. when I am using user.get_group_permissions() or user.get_all_permissions() then getting a list of all group permission or all permissions respectively but
when I am using user.user_permissions.all(), it's not showing me all permissions except group permissions.

is there any syntax to check any user group permission "user.get_group_permissions.has_perm('----')" as we do user.has_perm("----")?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [user.has_perm(...)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) or [user.has_perms(...)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms) methods to check the permissions

```
user.has_perm('app_name.permission_code_name')

#or

user.has_perms(['app_name.permission_code_name'])
```

You can also list the ***possible permission of a particular user*** by following this SO post,

1. [How to get user permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573174/how-to-get-user-permissions)

Comment: I need "has_perm" to check permissions if it exists in any group, user.has_perm() will work fine but.. any permission if not added by "user.user_permissions.add()" ...then user.has_perm() syntax will not give me True value....this syntax not check user group's permissions.

Comment: `has_perm()` will check the group level permissions too.

Comment: thanks, it's working, but we can't use a list in has_perm().

Comment: use `has_perms()` instead of `has_perm()` incase of list inputs