# Django: limit on permission_required size for TestCase? (PermissionRequiredMixin)

Tags: django, permissions, testcase

My test case raises a `django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied` exception even though `permission_required` and user permissions seem to be set right.

Here is the test case:

```
def test_create(self):
        """ Test view for creating a new category """

        response = self.client.get(reverse('category-create'), {'category': 1}, HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Here are the relevant views:

```
class AjaxMixin(PermissionRequiredMixin):
    """ AjaxMixin provides basic functionality for rendering a Django form to JSON. """

    # By default, allow *any* permissions
    permission_required = '*'

    def has_permission(self):
        """ Override the default behaviour of has_permission from PermissionRequiredMixin. """

        if self.permission_required == '*':
            return True
        else:
            return super().has_permission()


class CategoryCreate(AjaxMixin, CreateView):
    """ Create view to make a new PartCategory """

    # The problem is with 5 or more permissions, TestCase fails... no idea why!
    permission_required = ('part.add_part',
                           'part.add_bomitem',
                           'part.add_partcategory',
                           'part.add_partattachment',
                           'part.add_partsellpricebreak',
                           # 'part.add_parttesttemplate',
                           # 'part.add_partparametertemplate',
                           # 'part.add_partparameter'
                           )
```

If I comment `'part.add_partsellpricebreak',` in the `CategoryCreate` view, the get request response code is 200 and **no** exception is raised by the test case.
If I re-enable it, the test case breaks as stated above.

The `CategoryCreate` view works exactly as intended though the project's UI (eg. permissions are well managed, independently of the size of `permission_required`).

Any leads why is the test case failing when `permission_required` has a size of 5 or more?
Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: as per the doc of [**`has_perms(perm_list, obj=None)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms) there is no limit for the ***permissions*** to be checked. So, I suspect, the user doesn't have sufficient permissions.

Comment: I recommend to check whether the ***requested use*** has sufficient permissions by this way, [How to get user permissions in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573174/how-to-get-user-permissions)

Comment: Thanks @ArakkalAbu, I actually made a false assumption that any permission in the set should match user's permissions to be allowed... I was a little tired and didn't realized ALL permissions required need to match the user. So you are right and thanks for your comment!

Comment: I am glad that helped !!! @eeintech